# Memory Editing Functions

Tags: c++, memory, editing, standards

I'm looking for functions to write and read process memory similar to the Win32API calls in windows.h but I can't seem to find any for standard C++ and I would like it to be platform independent.

Comment: Process memory?  As in your own binary code?  Why?

Comment: Well for example I used to make some hacks for games and as I'm trying to get into writing cross-platform code I thought this would be a good project. My plan now is to just use something like #ifdef _WIN32 and write the function for each OS so when I call it, it will use whatever is necessary. I don't want to port though, I want it to compile on all three platforms with one code.

Comment: Which win32 functions are you trying to emulate?

Comment: The #ifdef solution is likely the correct one.

Answer (score 6):

There is no standard C++ API for accessing the memory of other processes. Standard C++ does not even have the concept of a 'process' at all. Moreover, the *contents* of the memory of other processes is highly platform-dependent, so adding a shim layer for porting to other OSes is the least of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can get platform independent because those kinds of API calls are dependent on the OS kernel, you'd need to create wrappers for each type(read, write) and change the internal API call based on a PP define (such as `_WIN32`)

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard supports memcpy(), memset(), memmove(), and memcmp().  There is also and STL utility, std::copy().  These are all platform independent.

Answer (score 0):

Which functions are you using on Windows? We're not sure what it is you're asking for, but if you show us what you're doing successfully there, we'll be able to help you find the equivalents on other platforms.